# C# Generic - Any way to declare T has an attribute?

Tags: c#, generics, custom-attributes

```
[MyCustomClassAttribute]
public class Foo
{
}


public class Bar<T>
    where T : ??
{
    public T FooInstance;
}
```

I'm pretty sure this is impossible, but just thought I'd check. Any way to make it so that T has to have a `[MyCustomClassAttribute]` on it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am afraid this is impossible. Here's a list of all the [possible generic constraints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx) you could use.

Comment: That's what I figured. Just thought I'd double check.